# javascript OCR API

Tags: javascript, json, api, ocr

I'm looking for a JavaScript OCR API.

Something like: send a picture and an expected result type (e.g. numbers, object, text, mixed, etc) and receive the result as a string or JSON.

Does anyone know of such an API/Service which you can access easily via JavaScript?

EDIT: 
I forgot to say, the main use case would be just to recognize numbers (like floats and doubles) and prices (e.g. 0.02$).

I already found some "cloud-ocr APIs" like abbyy, but they are expensive ... 2 cents per request...

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote a question. It is a fair question. Looking for an OCR web service with Javascript API.

Comment: [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) has a [REST API that's easy to use from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229168/javascript-text-recognition-and-ocr-on-canvas/38615942#38615942).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this is an old post, but the topic is still open and there are some new players now. You could use the [OCR API](https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis/ocrdocument) from [HP Haven OnDemand](https://www.havenondemand.com/). There are free developer accounts, you can try the API online with your own image, and they support JavaScript (amongst other languages) and provide output in JSON.

They also have a few tutorials for OCR with JavaScript that may be helpful to you.

1. [[javascript] Using OCR and Entity Extraction for LinkedIn Company Lookup](https://community.idolondemand.com/t5/Blog/javascript-Using-OCR-and-Entity-Extraction-for-LinkedIn-Company/ba-p/460)
2. [[JavaScript] Extracting Contact Information from Business Cards](https://community.idolondemand.com/t5/Blog/JavaScript-Extracting-Contact-Information-from-Business-Cards/ba-p/268)

Hopefully this helps.

Regards,

Hughesthe1st
(I work for HP)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ocrad.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js). Demos:

- [draw text](http://antimatter15.github.io/ocrad.js/demo.html)
- [use the webcam](https://kdzwinel.github.io/JS-OCR-demo/)

Comment: Do you have example for that. Or can you describe it a little bit more detailed?

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js
Demo Page: http://antimatter15.github.io/ocrad.js/demo.html

Comment: [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) is far more accurate than Ocrad and is [easy to use](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11357611).

Comment: There is a demo of client side javascript OCR primarily aimed at ID reading from webcams at https://www.imense.co.uk/DL.html