# JavaScript text recognition and OCR on <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, ocr, text-recognition

I found a web application that recognizes handwritten math equations:

> http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/equation.html?locale=default

I would like to know if someone knows an app or a tutorial or an open source project that implements this mechanism, because getting it from this webapp is really complex.

**Note:** I just need the equation drawn in the canvas to be translated in an input text box that's all.

Comment: Super cool find. It looks like they have some backend code turning coordinates into values for latex and json.

Answer (score 9):

[Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) has been [ported to JavaScript](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/).

Answer (score 7):

[Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) is a very accurate OCR service, and it's [free for up to 1000 requests per month](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing). It's also easy to use via its [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate). In the snippet below, the hard part is getting an image from the user and encoding it in Base64.

```js
var GCVUrl = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=XXX';
// Enable the Cloud Vision API and get a key - see
// https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var fileReader = new FileReader();

input.onchange = function (event) {

  var file = event.target.files[0];

  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    var GCVRequest = {
      requests: [{
        image: {
          content: fileLoadedEvent.target.result.split(',')[1]
          // must discard `data:image/png;base64,`
        },  
        features: [{type: 'TEXT_DETECTION'}]
      }]
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: GCVUrl,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(GCVRequest),
      success: function (data) {
        var texts;
        if (texts = data.responses[0].textAnnotations) {
          alert(texts[0].description);
        } else {
          alert('No text was recognized');
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert('XHR error: ' + jqXhr.responseJSON.error.message);
      }
    });

  };

  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Just a note on this, you now need a billing account and budget to not get a 403 error. Also I'm splitting on `';base64,'` not just comma.

Things I'd like to solve with it (probably async await & transpiler) are mapping multiple files to the request, then handle multiple responses.

Answer (score 4):

There are several emscripten.js ports of well known OCR libraries such as [OCRAD.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js) and [GOCR](https://github.com/antimatter15/gocr.js).