# Pass image to Tesseract.js OCR

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract

You can find the Tesseract JS Wrapper that I am referring to [here](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/#get_started).

What we want to accomplish:

- Upload a photo of a printed document
- Turn that photo into text

Things done to setup so far:

- `npm install tesseract.js`

Here is our code:

HTML

```
<input id="myFileInput" type="file" accept="image/*;" capture="camera">

<img id="pic" src="rec.jpg">
```

JS

```
<script src="http://tenso.rs/tesseract.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var img = document.getElementById("pic");

Tesseract
  .recognize( img, {
    progress: show_progress} )
  .then( display )

</script>
```

What's happening in the Console:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: show_progress is not defined"

"hallo",

"pre-main prep time: 67 ms",

---

As you can see, we've abandoned the photo upload feature for the moment, until we can figure out how to get tesseract.js to work for a single, pre-provided jpg. Eventually, we hope to add this functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, we're doing this for fun and are mainly seeking a simple (but effective) means of doing OCR with JavaScript. If you have another suggestion, please let us know!

Comment: You may want to compare the results vs. the [Google Cloud Vision API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229168/javascript-text-recognition-and-ocr-on-canvas/38615942#38615942).

Comment: Based on the answer given by user993553, you need to call a function for progress: . Or you need to write a function for show_progress.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/a6195ef86d9673cab26120613f53c499b8ec0994/example.htm it seems show_progress must be a function.

```
Tesseract.recognize(canvas,{
        tessedit_char_blacklist:'e',
        progress: function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code :

```
Tesseract.recognize("https://yoursite/image.jpg", {
    lang: 'ind',
    tessedit_char_blacklist: 'e'
})
.progress(function(message){ console.log(message) })
.then(function(result) { console.log(result) });
```

put `progress(function(message){ console.log(message) })` after the recognize function
and it works perfectly for me.